# How do you download data from API and export it into a nice CSV file to query?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-science, export-to-csv, data-analysis

I am trying to figure out how to 'download' data into a nice CSV file to be able to analyse.

I am currently looking at WHO data [here](https://www.who.int/data/gho/info/athena-api-examples):

I am doing so through following documentation and getting output like so:

```
test_data <- jsonlite::parse_json(url("http://apps.who.int/gho/athena/api/GHO/WHS6_102.json?profile=simple"))
head(test_data)
```

This gives me a rather messy list of list of lists.

For example:
[I get this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0a0H.png)

It is not very easy to analyse and rather messy. How could I clean this up by using say two columns that is returned from this json_parse, information only from say dim like REGION, YEAR, COUNTRY and then the values from the column Value. I would like to make this into a nice dataframe/CSV file so I can then more easily understand what is happening.

Can anyone give any advice?

Answer (score 0):

`jsonlite::fromJSON` gives you data in a better format and the 3rd element in the list is where the main data is.

```
url <- 'https://apps.who.int/gho/athena/api/GHO/WHS6_102.json?profile=simple'
tmp <- jsonlite::fromJSON(url) 
data <- tmp[[3]]
```